# How to get the objects of the other API?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

In assests folder  we have two json files called **1.customers** and **2.appointments**.
In **List component** i am displaying the list of customers as shown below.

[image]

Now i want to display the appointments of that particular customer as shown below.
[image]

Here is the stackblitz **[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-movie-read-load-json-sample-eg-6skgu8?file=src%2Fapp%2Flist%2Flist.component.html)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of putting too much logic into your templates, you can easily merge the data inside your `ContactsService` to fit your needs.

An example would be to use `combineLatest` to get the JSON data and then extend your customer with appointments.

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class ContactsService {
  private appointmentsData$ = this.http.get<IAppointments[]>(APPOINTMENTS_URL);
  private customersData$ = this.http.get<ICustomer[]>(CUSTOMERS_URL);


  public readonly customers$ = combineLatest(this.appointmentsData$, this.customersData$).pipe(
    map(([appointments, customers]) => {
      return customers.map(customer =>
      {
        return {
          ...customer,
          appointments: appointments.filter(appointment =>
          {
            return appointment.customerIds.indexOf(customer.id) > -1;
          })
        }
      })
    })
  );



  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
}
```

Then you can use the `customers$` observable inside your component and use the `async`-pipe to iterate over it inside your template:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-list',
  templateUrl: './list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./list.component.css']
})
export class ListComponent {
  public customers$ = this.contactsService.customers$;
  constructor(private contactsService: ContactsService) { }
}
```

```
<div class="main-div">
  <div *ngFor="let customer of customers$ | async">
    <p><b>Name:</b> {{customer.name}}</p>
    <h3>Appointments</h3>
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let appointment of customer.appointments">
        {{ appointment.appointmentName }}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

[**DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-movie-read-load-json-sample-eg-ke2rbj)

Answer (score 0):

If you add `appointments` to the `ListComponent` just as you did with `customers` you could do something like this in the template:

```
<div class="main-div">  
  <div *ngFor="let customer of customers">
    <p><b>Name:</b> {{customer.name}}</p>
    <h3>Appointments</h3>
    <ul>
      <ng-container *ngFor="let a of appointments">
        <li *ngIf="a.customerIds.includes(customer.id)">{{a.appointmentName}}</li>
      </ng-container>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```